# Functional and Borel measure

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, borel-sets

Let $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $g\in V$

Define functional $F:V \times\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$
$$(g,x)\mapsto F(g,x)$$

Since $\forall \text{operator }  T\  \exists\mu$ s.t. $  T(f)=\int_{\mathbb R} f \, d\mu$, where $\mu$ is a complex Borel measure,

Is it possible to prove that $\forall  F\  \exists\mu$ s.t. $  F(g,x)=\int_{-\infty}^x g \, d\mu$? or any similar forms.

On what kind of text I could learn more no this topic?

---

After some reading I find a possible way of doing this:

For any operator $F$ there exists another operator $T_x:V\to V$ s.t. $F(g,x)=T_x(g)$
then, if $T_x$ is continuous and linear,
$$T_x(g)=\int_\mathbb R gd\mu$$ where $\mu:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a Bounded variation (BV) function.

I am not sure that, in this case, whether $\mu$ has to be a complex Borel measure or just BV function is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Functional Analysis (Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics) by Reed & Simon" is your book. I've actually readed it a couple of days ago, it's in the chapter IV, sections 4 and 5. The theorem that you are talking sounds like the Riesz-Markov theorem and it works perfectly when your $V$ is in fact $C(X)$ with $X$ a compact set.